# How to upload a CSV file to 'openldap' and 'moodle' server?

Tags: server, moodle

I am new to Ubuntu server and trying to use `moodle` server for school. 
My purpose is to let students and teachers login to the server with user-name and password and enroll them to specific courses.

So I need to know how to upload the CSV file (an excel sheet contain the students and teachers information) to `openldap` and `moodle` servers.

Answer (score 1):

Moodle is web-based, you do not need the users to log into the server.  You have two choices with Moodle, the best is self-registration, but if you do want to upload a file you need to follow [these instructions in the documentation](https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/Upload_users#Uploading_users_via_text_file).

If you need them to all use the same machine to log on, then why not create a guest account that just logs them into the machine, other wise just give them the address of the moodle site you set up, and they can log into moodle from a web browser.